# How to analyze data efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

TLDR: I would like some suggestions on how I can improve my code.

I'm learning data science from datacamp, I have an beginner-intermediate knowledge about coding. This is a data-analysis project I did today and am not happy with my code since it feels jumbled and inefficient.

In the below code I'm supposed to find number of apps in each category and then make a new dataframe with category, number of apps, avg price and avg rating. I did a shit job so would like some helpful tips

```
    num_apps = apps["Category"].value_counts(sort=False)
num_app = num_apps.sort_index()
avg_price = apps.groupby('Category')['Price'].mean()
avg_rat = apps.groupby('Category')['Rating'].mean()

Average_price = avg_price.values.tolist()
Average_rat = avg_rat.values.tolist()
number_of_apps = num_app.values.tolist()

cat = apps['Category'].drop_duplicates()
Categor = cat.values.tolist()
Category = np.sort(Categor)

dict_list = {
    'Category': Category,
    'Number of apps': number_of_apps,
    'Average price': Average_price,
    'Average rating': Average_rat
}
app_category_info = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you take a look at the docs, and read about [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) functions.

Since you can perform multiple aggregations on a `groupby`, you would get a performance improvement by taking advantage of those functions like this:

```
d = {'Category':'Number of apps','Price':'Average price','Rating':'Average rating'}
df.groupby('Category').agg({'Category': 'count', 
                            'Price': 'mean', 
                            'Rating': 'mean'}).rename(columns=d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that for someone in your position an article like this might be the most helpful (geared towards data-analysis-in-Python best style practices):
https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/six-steps-to-more-professional-data-science-code

A few random comments on your code:

```
num_apps = apps["Category"].value_counts(sort=False)
num_app = num_apps.sort_index()
```

The names do not distinguish between the two variables clearly. Do you need to even keep the first one (you don't use it again)? Do you need to pass `sort=False` when you immediately do another sort?

```
avg_price = apps.groupby('Category')['Price'].mean()
avg_rat = apps.groupby('Category')['Rating'].mean()

Average_price = avg_price.values.tolist()
Average_rat = avg_rat.values.tolist()
```

Again, you have variables with the same name, except inconsistent capitalisation and naming structure (`avg` vs `Average`). It's not clear to a reader what the difference is. How about `avg_price_list`?

```
number_of_apps = num_app.values.tolist()

cat = apps['Category'].drop_duplicates()
Categor = cat.values.tolist()
Category = np.sort(Categor)
```

Again, these variables are not great...

```
dict_list = {
    'Category': Category,
    'Number of apps': number_of_apps,
    'Average price': Average_price,
    'Average rating': Average_rat
}
app_category_info = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

Overall, the whole structure is a bit strange. You're starting with a DataFrame, then often changing things into lists, then into a dictionary, then back to a DataFrame.

In general the point of using Pandas is that it provides functions for you - you don't need to spend a lot of time manually converting between datatypes (although, sometimes of course manual hints or raw Python are required). I'd suggest trying to stick to "Pandas mindset" rather than mixing different approaches in one. You can probably condense the code then.

But, primary suggestion for now, first clear up your variable names, that will make a big step forward to understandable / clear code ;-)

Comment: I'll improve my use of variable names and as for converting them into a list I did it because i was having trouble in making the new data frame "app_category_info" so the converting them into lists was the solution I came up with

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense and good try as a first approach. @Afonso provides a good solution that goes directly to what I meant - if you study the Pandas functions well, you can usually do it all in one in there! Hope my comments were helpful anyway.

Comment: @zero, if you find one of the answers helpful please mark it as an accepted answer :-)